# Magento - Can I store data in a helper, from an observer to then call in a block.php

Tags: php, magento

I am having problems passing data from my observer straight to my block.  It seems like the block "doesn't exist" until after my observer trys to push the data to it.  I use the following code to push the an order ID to my block to then call all the order info into that block:

```
public function setCappsCactOnOrderSuccessPageView(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
    if (empty($orderIds) || !is_array($orderIds)) {
        return;
    }
    $block = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getLayout()->getBlock('capps_cact');
    if ($block) {
        $block->setOrderIds($orderIds);     
    }
}
```

When i then do this in my block, the variable is empty:

```
$orderIds = $this->getOrderIds();
if (empty($orderIds) || !is_array($orderIds)) {
        echo ('This is empty');
        return;
    } else {
        echo ('That worked correctly');
```

So what I am wondering is if I can push $orderIds to a data.php helper and then call it back into my block once it exsists.

I hope that made sense.  I just need to store the variable from my observer and call it back into my block.

Comment: Are you trying to retrieve the orderID of the order just placed, then render that information in your block?

Comment: Yes and no. I need to just show my code once though. I know that this works to get the order ID, $orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
 $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);

Comment: but i just need it to show on the success page and no other pages

Comment: If you know how to retrieve it, why aren't you trying to do so from your block, rather than trying to inject the variable?

Just load the block on your success page, and have that block access the data and display it.

Comment: The way I am loading the block is by checking if there was an order ID.  that order ID followed the customer after they left the success page, so the block would show on every subsequent page.  Turns out I can just add another block to the success page that clears the session.  That was a much easier way to accomplish what I needed.